# how to prevent password prompt pops up many times

Tags: applescript

My code looks like:

```
set sourceFolder1 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL.framework"

set sourceFolder2 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_ttf.framework"

set sourceFolder3 to (path to library folder as text) & "Frameworks:SDL_image.framework"


tell application "Finder"

if exists folder sourceFolder1 then

    delete folder sourceFolder1
end if


if exists folder sourceFolder2 then

    delete folder sourceFolder2
end if


if exists folder sourceFolder3 then

    delete folder sourceFolder3
end if


end tell
```

When I test it, the password prompt pops up 3 times to ask for password. Is there a way to prevent the password prompt pops up more than once? Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the password prompt pops up more than once : Use the `delete` command only once by putting all the folders or files in a list.

Like this:

```
set frmWKsList to {}
set librF to path to library folder as text
set end of frmWKsList to librF & "Frameworks:SDL.framework"
set end of frmWKsList to librF & "Frameworks:SDL_ttf.framework"
set end of frmWKsList to librF & "Frameworks:SDL_image.framework"

set foldersToDelete to {}
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with i in frmWKsList
        if exists folder i then set end of foldersToDelete to i as alias
    end repeat

    delete foldersToDelete
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

The Finder is asking for password because you're trying to remove a file from a location that the user doesn't have delete privileges for.

One way to solve this would be to do the deletion via shell commands. Replace `delete folder sourcefolder1` with:

```
do shell script ("rm -rf '" & posix path of sourcefolder1 & "'") ¬
    with administrator privileges user name "username" password "password"
```

Then it won't ask at all. If you want it to ask once, remove everything from `user name` onward. It will remember the entry for the subsequent commands.

**Update**: per comment below, the need is to be able to move the item to the Trash rather than delete it outright as `rm` does. I couldn't think of any way to do it in straight AppleScript, because the administrator prompting is coming from the Finder, and AppleScript (as far as I know) can only perform a privileged action programmatically with the `do shell script` command. So I wrote a routine that should be equivalent to "Move To Trash" in the Finder:

```
to deleteItem(thisItem)
    set thisItemPath to (POSIX path of thisItem)
    set uid to (do shell script "id -u")
    if thisItemPath starts with "/Volumes" then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
        set volName to text item 3 of thisItemPath
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        set targetPath to ¬
            ("/Volumes/" & volName & "/.Trashes/" & uid)
    else
        set targetPath to ((POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & ".Trash")
    end if
    set moveToTrashCmd to ¬
      ("mkdir -p '" & targetPath & "'; " & ¬
      "mv '" & thisItemPath & "' '" & targetPath & "'")
    -- set global vars first for userName and password, or omit for prompt
    do shell script moveToTrashCmd ¬
       with administrator privileges user name userName password userPw
    end if
end deleteItem
```

Here's a sample program that uses the routine:

```
global fileItems, userName, userPw

on run
    set userPw to "password"
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    set userName to text item -2 of (path to home folder as string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    try
        fileItems
    on error
        set fileItems to ¬
          (choose folder with prompt ¬
          "Select folders to delete:" with multiple selections allowed)
    end try
    repeat with thisItem in fileItems
        deleteItem(thisItem)
    end repeat
end run

-- drag 'n' dropped files
on open docs
    set fileItems to docs
    run
end open
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. But, if I use rm -rf , the folder will be deleted, instead of moving to the trash folder as delete folder does. Is there a way to do the similar thing with applescript? The reason I use applescript is that I can move folders to the trash, then later if user want to put back the folder, they have the option of put back. If I use shell script, no put back option available. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the command to provide a way of moving to trash without the administrator prompt.